# Managing ECR lifecycle policies using SAM for docker-based lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I’m working on a SAM app with several lambda functions. The lambda functions are deployed using docker through ECR. Every time a new function is deployed, it creates a new image in ECR. This is going to grow out of hand fast. Is there a way to make SAM configure a lifecycle policy on every image repository, so that old images get deleted automatically?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy using AWS SAM, you yourself have control over the S3 bucket/ECR repository it uses to upload the zipfiles/images. This means that AWS SAM cannot set a lifecycle policy on the ECR repository, since it doesn't manage the repository itself, it only uses the repository to upload the images.

You can of course manage a [lifecycle policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html) yourself on the ECR repository, in order to remove unused and old images.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to set the lifecycle policy automatically? Because when you create an ECR as a SAM resource, you can set its lifecycle policy. I tried to then use that repository as the function repository using `ImageUri: !GetAtt SeleniumRepo.RepositoryUri`, but SAM just ignored that.

Comment: The repository to use for uploading the image, should be passed along to the AWS SAM cli command, not in the CloudFormation resource. You should simply set the uri as relative path and AWS SAM should bundle and upload the code. The repository you pass to the cli command can be managed in a separate CloudFormation stack.